# EXCEL: If customer invoice appears in current month and same period previous year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am trying to identify whether a customer has been invoices in current month and if they were also invoiced in the same month previous year.

the fields below

| Report_Month | cl_Code | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/08/2023 | KEN166 | 64 |
| 31/08/2023 | INSUR4 | 513.92 |
| 31/08/2023 | EDI003 | 30 |
| 31/08/2023 | BLI039 | 40 |
| 31/08/2023 | MCL031 | 80 |
| 31/08/2023 | TRA060 | 341.42 |
| 31/08/2023 | MYE013 | 88 |
| 31/08/2023 | YOU274 | 162.18 |
| 31/08/2023 | SAM015 | 884.42 |
| 31/08/2023 | PAR099 | 436.5 |
| 31/08/2023 | WWESPS | 15.54 |
| 31/08/2023 | ALL376 | 51 |
| 31/08/2023 | ALM067 | 39.5 |
| 31/08/2023 | CUS039 | 42.8 |
| 31/08/2023 | MOO119 | 102 |
| 31/08/2023 | REGAL | 71.83 |
| 31/08/2023 | KID005 | 40 |
| 31/08/2023 | WOM002 | 1048.55 |
| 31/08/2023 | BIL018 | 125.7 |
| 31/08/2023 | CAR821 | 23.66 |
| 31/08/2023 | WBG001 | 72.4 |
| 31/08/2023 | FOS031 | 52 |
| 31/08/2023 | WTG | 345.98 |
| 31/08/2022 | INSUR4 | 513.92 |
| 31/08/2022 | EDI003 | 30 |
| 31/08/2022 | BLI039 | 40 |
| 31/08/2022 | MCL031 | 80 |
| 31/08/2022 | TRA060 | 341.42 |
| 31/08/2022 | MYE013 | 88 |
| 31/08/2022 | YOU274 | 162.18 |
| 31/08/2022 | SAM015 | 884.42 |
| 31/08/2022 | PAR099 | 436.5 |
| 31/08/2022 | WWESPS | 15.54 |
| 31/08/2022 | ALL376 | 51 |
| 31/08/2022 | ALM067 | 39.5 |
| 31/08/2022 | CUS039 | 42.8 |

What i would like to do is if customers are in the visible in the same period have column say 1 if not 0. But i would like to be able to change the periods im comparing so for next month i can change formula so it looks at september

results below

| Report_Month | cl_Code | Revenue | Organic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/08/2023 | KEN166 | 64 | 0 |
| 31/08/2023 | INSUR4 | 513.92 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | EDI003 | 30 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | BLI039 | 40 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | MCL031 | 80 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | TRA060 | 341.42 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | MYE013 | 88 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | YOU274 | 162.18 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | SAM015 | 884.42 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | PAR099 | 436.5 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | WWESPS | 15.54 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | ALL376 | 51 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | ALM067 | 39.5 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | CUS039 | 42.8 | 1 |
| 31/08/2023 | MOO119 | 102 | 0 |
| 31/08/2023 | REGAL | 71.83 | 0 |
| 31/08/2023 | KID005 | 40 | 0 |
| 31/08/2023 | WOM002 | 1048.55 | 0 |
| 31/08/2023 | BIL018 | 125.7 | 0 |
| 31/08/2023 | CAR821 | 23.66 | 0 |
| 31/08/2023 | WBG001 | 72.4 | 0 |
| 31/08/2023 | FOS031 | 52 | 0 |
| 31/08/2023 | WTG | 345.98 | 0 |
| 31/08/2022 | INSUR4 | 513.92 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | EDI003 | 30 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | BLI039 | 40 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | MCL031 | 80 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | TRA060 | 341.42 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | MYE013 | 88 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | YOU274 | 162.18 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | SAM015 | 884.42 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | PAR099 | 436.5 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | WWESPS | 15.54 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | ALL376 | 51 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | ALM067 | 39.5 | 1 |
| 31/08/2022 | CUS039 | 42.8 | 1 |

i have tried the following

`=IFS($D$4:$D$39=D4,1,$C$4:$C$39,">="&"31/08/2022")` but everything returns as 1

additionally tried `=IF(AND($C$4:$C$39>="31/08/2022",$D$4:$D$39=D4),1,0)` but all returned 0

thank in advance

Comment: In accordance with the forum guidelines, please edit your question to show what you have tried and where your method has resulted in a problem or error.

Comment: `=(INT($C$4:$C$39)>="31/08/2022")*($D$4:$D$39=D4)`

Comment: @ScottCraner returns 0 for all did it with cntrl shift enter

Comment: maybe: `=IF(COUNTIFS($D$4:$D$39,D4,$C$4:$C$39,">="&"31/08/2022"),1,0)`?

Comment: sorry only just managed to get back to this - this didnt work either everything returned as 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made use of a **Table** with structured references, but you could change it to regular addressing if you prefer. The table structure has the advantage of not having to hard-code cell ranges.

I named the table `Report`

Enter the formula below in the first cell of the `Organic` column and it should copy down to the end of the Table column

```
=N(
    (
        COUNTIFS(
            [Report_Month], ">" &
                EOMONTH([@[Report_Month]], -13),
            [Report_Month], "<=" &
                EOMONTH([@[Report_Month]], -12),
            [cl_Code], [@[cl_Code]]
        ) +
            COUNTIFS(
                [Report_Month], ">" &
                    EOMONTH([@[Report_Month]], 11),
                [Report_Month], "<=" &
                    EOMONTH([@[Report_Month]], 12),
                [cl_Code], [@[cl_Code]]
            )
    ) > 0
)
```

The formula looks for a match either 12 months in the past or, since you also want the past month marked, 12 months in the future.

We compare the result to `0` in the event that you have more than one matching entry in the corresponding month (and then use the `N` function to convert that to a `1` or `0` as you show for your desired result).

The month being checked will always be the month in the `[Report_Month]` column for any particular entry.

[image]

Comment: sorry just got back to looking at this. This works on a smaller scale. If i expand list to look at more dates and customers and If i want to refine the formula to lets say.. only put 1 for client where they were explicit in Aug-22 and find the customer in Aug-23. I amended your formula to replace the @report_month with specific date "31/08/023" but that returned 1's for everything

Comment: @Fazza It works on the data you presented. Not surprising that it is not working on the data you have since, apparently, the data and questions you presented are not truly representative of what you really have and want.

Comment: it was more of a comment on how i could make your formula dynamic to specific month & year. but thank you nonetheless

Comment: @Fazza If I understand you correctly, I think that is a different scenario than what you posted. After all, if `Report_Month` is not the same as `Specific_month` then only 0's would be returned given your data. I think you should accept what you feel is the best answer to **this** question and then ask a new one (with examples) that explains your other problem more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Apply formula on cell F2, and fill through to the last row

- `Date` will generate a date, the parameters are: year, month, date
- `CountIf` to count how many D4 in column D ($D$4:$D$39)

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($D$4:$D$39,D4)>1,C4>DATE(2023,8,23)),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the `DAY()`, `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions, showing the day, month and year of a date?

Here's an example in a screenshot:

[image]

(For your information: the date format is European style ("dd-mm-yyyy").)